# ffmpeg, scale and hardcoded subs

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to scale a video and hardcode subs in it.

I tried :

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "scale=1280:720; subtitles=sub.srt" out.mp4
```

but I only get a:

> was expected to have exactly 1 input and 1 output. However, it had >1
>   input(s) and >1 output(s). Please adjust, or use a complex filtergraph
>   (-filter_complex) instead.

Do you know what's wrong ? Should I use filter_complex ? Because it looks very cryptic to me…

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "scale=1280:720, subtitles=sub.srt" out.mp4
```

i.e. replace `;` with `,`. `;` is used to terminate filterchains which are linear sequence of filters each operating on the output of the previous filter. So, with the `;`. you start a new chain which expects a labeled input or one from a different source.